# Getting scalatest to run from databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, scalatest

What's missing in order to get this simple scalatest working in databricks? (mostly as per their userguide)

1. I have cluster, into which I've uploaded the following latest scalatest jar and restarted cluster:
   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.13/3.2.13/scalatest_2.13-3.2.13.jar
2. Following: https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_shell
   I'm running their sample code:

```scala
import org.scalatest._

class ArithmeticSuite extends AnyFunSuite with matchers.should.Matchers {
   test("addition works") { 
     1 + 1 should equal (2)
   } 
} 
run(new ArithmeticSuite)
```

[image: screenshot of code as the above isn't formatting properly here]

The errors start with:

```
command-1362189841383727:3: error: not found: type AnyFunSuite
class ArithmeticSuite extends AnyFunSuite with matchers.should.Matchers {
                              ^
command-1362189841383727:3: error: object should is not a member of package org.scalatest.matchers
class ArithmeticSuite extends AnyFunSuite with matchers.should.Matchers {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to use scalatest test structure for 3.0.8
https://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/3.0.8/org/scalatest/FeatureSpec.html

```
  <artifactId>scalatest_2.12</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.8</version>
```

to match the version 3.0.8 included with databricks runtime

This resolved our errors

Answer (score 0):

Databricks clusters are using Scala 2.12, while you have installed library compiled for Scala 2.13 that is binary incompatible with Databricks cluster. Take version for Scala 2.12 (with `_2.12` suffix).

P.S. Although scalatest already could be a part of Databricks Runtime - check it by running `%sh ls -ls /databricks/jars/*scalatest*`

Comment: Alex thanks for your answer. Following your advice,  I've changed to  
scalatest_2_13_3_2_12.jar 

and can confirm my cluster has spec:
 DBR 7.3 LTS | spark 3.0.1 | scala 2.12

However, after restarting cluster, I still get the above error. 

If relevant, I also get: 
ls: cannot access '/dataricks/jars/*scalatest*': No such file or directory

Comment: Also, I can run a sample test located within a "sampleTest" class from intelliJ (maven project using scalatest 2_12, and scala version 2.12.12) using a cluster of DBR 7.3 LTS | spark 3.0.1 | scala 2.12 -- however when building a fat jar and having only this jar available to the cluster, and calling "sampleTest" class within databricks gives:

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method uk/os/ngd/consistentdata/testSuite.org$scalatest$Assertions$_setter_$assertionsHelper_$eq(Lorg/scalatest/Assertions$AssertionsHelper;)V is abstract